# Using Python 3.1 with TextMate

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, textmate

TextMate seems to use the built-in Python version I assume (sys.path doesn't work). How do you configure it to use 3.1 instead? I've already installed the 3.1 package and I can use IDLE for interactive sessions, but I need to use TextMate now.

Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

TextMate uses the value of the `TM_PYTHON` variable to find the path to the Python interpreter.  A good solution is to take advantage of TextMate's ability to define variables like `TM_PYTHON` on a per-project basis:

1. Open a new or existing TextMate Project (`File -> New Project` or `File -> Open`)
2. De-select any file in the project list sidebar.
3. Click on the `Get Info` (**i**) icon in the sidebar.  A `Project Information` pane appears.
4. Click + to add a new variable.
5. Enter TM_PYTHON in the Variable field and the full path to the desired python in the Value field (for example, `/usr/local/bin/python3.1`).
6. Close the Information window and save the Project (`File` -> `Save Project As`).

Then you can add files as needed to the project and they will be run under the chosen python with TextMate Python bundle's Run Script command.  You might want to save a `Python 3` project, say, for running ad-hoc scripts under Python 3.  For bigger projects, you'll want to create a separate TextMate project for it anyway.

To change the Python version used globally within `TextMate`:

1. From the `TextMate` menu bar, open `TextMate` -> `Preferences`
2. click on the `Advanced` pane
3. click on the `Shell Variable` tab
4. click the `+` to add a new variable
5. enter `TM_PYTHON` in the `Variable` field and the full path to the python in the `Value` field (perhaps `/usr/local/bin/python3.1`)

As Alex points out, you may break other TextMate functionality by changing the Python version globally so the per-project change is probably a better solution.

UPDATE (2010-10-31):

There is another approach that may be easier to use for some projects.  The `Run` command in `TextMate`'s Python bundle appears to respect a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line in the file being run.  So, instead of modifying `TM_PYTHON`, you can specify the path to the interpreter to be used by including a first line like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.1

# sample code to show version
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

In many case you would prefer not to *hardwire* the absolute path but manage use through the normal shell `PATH` environment variable.  Traditionally `/usr/bin/env` is used for that purpose.  However when running under `TextMate`, your shell profile files are not normally used so any changes to PATH do not show up there including possibly `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/local/bin` or wherever your desired `python3` command is located.  To get around that, you can add or modify a global `PATH` shell variable to `TextMate` -> `Preferences` (see above) with a value of, say, `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`.  Then you can use a more general shebang line like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

(This all seems to work with the most recent vanilla `TextMate` and its Python bundle: no guarantees about earlier versions or with other Python bundles.)

Comment: I can't figure this out...perhaps because I am using TextMate 2.0-alpha9495. There is no advanced pane, nor can I find a new project option. I also do not see a shebang line, just some ruby code.

Comment: TextMate 2 has changed much of the old project folder feature found in TM1.  TM2 has a much more flexible way of specifying all sorts of settings, including `PATH` variables, on a hierarchical, per-folder basis using `.tm_properties` files.  See, for instance: http://blog.macromates.com/2011/git-style-configuration/

Answer (score 9):

Late to the party, sorry! I take it you want to run the script using TextMate's 'built-in' interpreter? I've found the simplest solution is to add a shebang, which works extremely well;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

for python 3.1 or;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

for default system python, although the latter is superfluous for the exercise.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this long thread](http://old.nabble.com/using-python-3.0.1-td22499054.html) (which was about Python 3.0, and the TextMate version existing back last spring, but I believe is still valid for Python 3.1 and today's TextMate), you can get it done (e.g. via @Ned's answer), but once you do many TextMate commands may well break (because they're written to use Python 2, and Python 3 is not backwards compatible with Python 2 -- for example, the use of `reload`, which disappeared in Python 3, is repeatedly mentioned in the thread).  Still, it might work if you do not use or need much of TextMate's functionality (LaTeX typesetting for example was mentioned as something that totally breaks once you make TextMate use Python 3 instead of Python 2).

Comment: I've updated the answer to include how to set variables on a per-project basis.  That should prevent the breakage!

Comment: Erm...you guys are scaring me with the details! I just need to run 3.1 with Textmate for basic learning! :) I added TM_PYTHON:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin/python3.1 as Ned instructed and its now using Python3.1 — It doesn't show any details with sys.path, but I tried this: print ("Is this {}? — {}".format('Python 3.1', 'Yes!')) and it worked! Thanks heaps! :)

Answer (score 4):

the shebang is the best solution, to see where python 3 is installed type in terminal:

> which python3

you will get something like this:

> /usr/local/bin/python3

if nothing shows up first install python3

and at the top of your script insert:

> #!/usr/local/bin/python3

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve this in TextMate version `2.0.23` with the aim to use `python3` as the default.

So this is how I could set the `TM_PYTHON` variable (based on [@Ned Deily's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776026/784318) above):

1. Open Textmate
2. Hit `CMD + ;` to open the settings
   [image]
3. Now Add a new Variable with the `+` sign

4. In the Terminal.app I typed `which python3` which gave me `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

Now whenever I open a python script and hit `CMD + R` it will execute as a `pyhton3` script by default while "honouring" the installed PIP packages.