# Debugging python using Textmate?

Tags: python, debugging, textmate, textmatebundles

I'd like to use TextMate for debugging python scripts.  I'm looking for suggestions on the best way to accomplish this.  I found these "solutions" -- is there a better approach?

http://www.libertypages.com/clarktech/?p=192 
[Using Python 3.1 with TextMate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775954/using-python-3-1-with-textmate)

I'd really like to find something as usable as the Eclipse PyDev plugin, if at all possible, with these key features:

- current debug line selected in TextMate
- variable inspection in TextMate
- debug commands as buttons in TextMate (step, stop, ...)
- customizable PYTHONPATH and/or launch script per project

The last feature is to support my app engine testing, where I frequently launch a python shell by

```
python2.5 appengine_console.py my-app-id localhost:8080
```

Finally, I am open to writing a plugin as a last resort if it is possible to achieve good integration.  If you suggest custom development and have pointers on to assess the effort and get started, please include that in your answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TextMate is not an IDE, it's just an awsome editor.

Therefore you'll find that these features might not be available, and that you should just debug from the provided command line.

Comment: Thomas, I know TextMate is an editor.  What I don't know is how people use it for debugging python, and how close to IDE functionality you can get.  Do you use TextMate for debugging python?  If so, do you use the PdbTextMateSupport bundle?  It looks stale, and I wonder if there are better alternatives....  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thomas, I'm trying to be nice, but let me be a little more blunt: do you have suggestions for better practices for using TextMate for debugging?  I obviously know the current limitations, and as I explained I am also aware of the differences between IDEs and editors.

Answer (score 0):

You really should consider using Eclipse and PyDev.

I'd prefer TextMate over Eclipse too but there's no good debugger in TextMate, as far as I know.