# Why type coercion works differently on scripts / interactive prompt?

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.1.2 (Mac OS X 10.6) and found this weird behavior (I'm a newbie, btw):

On the interactive prompt:

```
>>> fraction = 4 / 3
>>> print(fraction)
1.33333333333
>>> print(type(fraction))
<class 'float'>
```

However, if I do the same thing in a script, results are different:

```
## fraction.py

fraction = 4 / 3
print(fraction)
print(type(fraction))
```

Output:

```
1
<class 'int'>
```

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not normal. Are you sure you are running Python 3 in that script? It's possible that Python 2.5 (the default install on Mac OS X) is chosen. Try to verify by

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

If you are running the script as `./fraction.py`, you could force the shell to use Python 3.1 by putting

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.1
```

in the first line.

Comment: You're right. I'm using TextMate (a text editor) which has an automated mechanism for testing Python scripts and it's probably calling an older version (although in the output it reads 3.1.2). I double checked in the command line and you're right, there's something wrong with TextMate (not with Python). Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775954/using-python-3-1-with-textmate/ for how to use Python 3 with TextMate.

Answer (score 1):

What KennyTM said. The reason is that in Python <3, `/` signifies integer division if both arguments are integers. This was silly, and was changed in Py3k so that `/` always returns a `float`, even if dividing `int`s.

Comment: I knew there was a difference, but forgot to double check if I was running the right version before posting the question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Andreas Fernandes If you need the 3.0 behavior in 2.x, put `from __future__ import division` as the first line in your script