# How do I use Python 3.1.2 in Textmate?

Tags: python, textmate

TextMate 1.5.9 seems to use Python 2.6.1. How do you configure it to use 3.1 instead? I've already installed the 3.1 package and I can use IDLE for interactive sessions, but I want to use TextMate now. I've already seen the post that directs you to define a project variable (TM_PYTHON : interpreter path). I tried this, but when i use Cmd+r to run a script in Textmate I still see Python 2.6.1 as the version number (top/right). Even the Terminal uses 2.7!

Help!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775954/using-python-3-1-with-textmate).  It should work but make sure you are using the right path to the Python 3.1 you installed.  Check with:

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

If you used the python.org 3.1 installer, it should be available at `/usr/local/bin/python3`.  Other methods may vary, for instance, the MacPorts python3.1 would normally be at `/opt/local/bin/python3`.

UPDATE: Since you indicate that it still doesn't work for you, my guess is that we are using different versions of TextMate's Python bundle.  Using the TextMate Bundle Editor (menu item `Bundles -> Bundle Editor -> Show Bundle Editor`) then selecting the Python bundle's `Run Script` command, I see the following command snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"] + "/lib/tm/executor"
require ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"] + "/lib/tm/save_current_document"

TextMate.save_current_document
TextMate::Executor.make_project_master_current_document

ENV["PYTHONPATH"] = ENV["TM_BUNDLE_SUPPORT"] + (ENV.has_key?("PYTHONPATH") ? ":" + ENV["PYTHONPATH"] : "")

is_test_script = ENV["TM_FILEPATH"] =~ /(?:\b|_)(?:test)(?:\b|_)/ or
                 File.read(ENV["TM_FILEPATH"]) =~ /\bimport\b.+(?:unittest)/

TextMate::Executor.run(ENV["TM_PYTHON"] || "python", "-u", ENV["TM_FILEPATH"]) do |str, type|
  if is_test_script and type == :err
    if str =~ /\A[\.F]*\Z/
      str.gsub!(/(\.|F)/, "<span class=\"test ok\">\\1</span>")
      str + "<br/>\n"
    elsif str =~ /\A(FAILED.*)\Z/
      "<div class=\"test fail\">#{htmlize $1}</div>\n"
    elsif str =~ /\A(OK.*)\Z/
      "<div class=\"test ok\">#{htmlize $1}</div>\n"
    elsif str =~ /^(\s+)File "(.+)", line (\d+), in (.*)/
      indent = $1
      file   = $2
      line   = $3
      method = $4
      indent += " " if file.sub!(/^\"(.*)\"/,"\1")
      url = "&amp;url=file://" + e_url(file)
      display_name = ENV["TM_DISPLAYNAME"]
      "#{htmlize(indent)}<a class=\"near\" href=\"txmt://open?line=#{line + url}\">" +
        (method ? "method #{CGI::escapeHTML method}" : "<em>at top level</em>") +
        "</a> in <strong>#{CGI::escapeHTML display_name}</strong> at line #{line}<br/>\n"
    end
  end
end
```

Check and see if you have the same.  If not, you should consider updating TextMate and/or the bundle. The `GetBundle` bundle makes it easy to keep bundles up-to-date as described [here](http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2009/02/25/installing-getbundles-on-a-fresh-copy-of-textmate/).

Comment: Typing "which python3" in the terminal window yields "/usr/local/bin/python3". So as per the referenced post, I created a new project in TM, hit cmd+i on the project and added a project variable "TM_PYTHON" with a value of "/usr/local/bin/python3". 

When I hit cmd+r I get Textmate's python window (whatever its called) and in the top right it says "Python 2.6.1"

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

Take away this normal she bang from your script then run it you will then have version 3 show up in textmates window. The default shebang overrides the variable and sends you back to osx default version 2.6.1. It is all a bit weird....