# TextMate doesn't perform encode() function in python

Tags: python, encode, textmate

friends.

I deal with an issue in TextMate, which I use to write code normally.

For my hash map script I need to encode a string into bytes.

As an example if I write:

```
password = "orange"
bytes_list = list(password.encode())
print(bytes_list)
```

The expected output is `[111, 114, 97, 110, 103, 101]` which I get if I run the script from Python's IDLE and even if I write the same code in my shell.


But if I run the code in TextMate, the result yields `['o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e']`, so it's obvious, that the **encode()** function in TextMate is not working as expected.

The funny part is, that if I execute the code from TextMate to shell it doesn't work neither.


In the preferences of TextMate the Encoding is set to **Unicode - UTF-8** and the Unicode bundle is installed.

I couldn't find any answer via Google to this topic. Maybe some of you came across such issue in the past.


Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TextMate is using Python 2.7:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Dec  3 2019, 07:02:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> password = "orange"
>>> bytes_list = list(password.encode())
>>> print(bytes_list)
['o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e']
>>>
```

Python 3 will give the output you expected:

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 03:13:28) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> password = "orange"
>>> bytes_list = list(password.encode())
>>> print(bytes_list)
[111, 114, 97, 110, 103, 101]
>>>
```

Comment: See this post for using Python 3 with TextMate: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775954/using-python-3-1-with-textmate